# How to prove this propositional logic equivalence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Problem : $\lnot[(\lnot p∧q)∨\lnot q]∨[\lnot(p∧\lnot q)]≡\lnot p∨q$  Prove this equility without using truth table.

I have managed to solve this question until this part :
$$\begin{align}\lnot[(\lnot p∧q)∨[\lnot(p∧\lnot q)] &≡ [\lnot(\lnot p∧q)∧q]∨(\lnot p∨q)\\& ≡ [(p∧q)∨(\lnot q∧q)]∨(\lnot p∨q)]\\&  ≡ (p∧q)∨(\lnot p∨q)\end{align}$$

I stucked here. I tried to $(p∧q)∨\lnot(p∧\lnot q)$ like this for de morgan rule but it doesnt work. What do I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can I add images instead of writing the problem?

Comment: It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Okay thx I hope someone can clear my this doubt :(( I don't know what to do for next step

Comment: Can someone help find a better title for this question. This current title is not very informative.

Comment: The title "How to prove this propositional logic equivalence?" would make it more likely that people would help.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $((p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \lor q)) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor q)$ by the fact that
$$((\phi \rightarrow \psi) \land (\psi \rightarrow \phi)) \rightarrow (\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)$$ where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are arbitrary propositions.

Thus, all you have to show that

\begin{align}
(\lnot p \lor q) &\rightarrow ((p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \lor q)) && (1) \\
((p \land q) \lor (\lnot p \lor q)) &\rightarrow (\lnot p \lor q) && (2)
\end{align}

The first statement is the definition of $\lor \text{ Introduction}$, and the second is proved trivially by $\lor \text{ Elimination}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go on...

$\begin{align}& [(p ∧ q) ∨ (\lnot p ∨ q)]\\ \equiv~& [((p ∧ q) ∨ \lnot p) ∨ q] \\ \equiv~& [((p ∨ \lnot p) ∧ (\lnot p ∨ q)) ∨ q]\\ \equiv~& [(\text T ∧ (\lnot p ∨ q)) ∨ q]\\ \equiv~& [(\lnot p ∨ q) ∨ q]\\\equiv~& [\lnot p ∨ (q ∨ q)]\\ \equiv~& (\lnot p ∨ q)\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Start by opening everything up.
=> ~[(~p v ~q) ^ (q v ~q)] v (~p v q)
=> ~[(~p v ~q) ^ T] v (~p v q)
=> ~(~p v ~q) v (~p v q)
=> (p ^ q) v ~p v q
=> (p v ~p) ^ (q v ~p) v q
=> T ^ (~p v q) v q
=> ~p v q